# CSS and images - why picture isn't resized

Tags: css, image

Why when I want to resize div, image in div doesn't change its size !? It's CASCADE style sheets, isn't it?

--EDIT--

```
.box{padding:0px;margin-left:10px;display:inline-block;margin-right:auto;width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid red;}

<div class="box">
<img src="larrow.gif"/>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the size of the image specified?

Comment: Does the selector for applying the style match the `img`?

Answer (score 4):

It's cascade, but width and height are not inherited.

You might want to do something to make the image follow the size of its parent.

Like

```
div.box img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: I have a question tho: When does the image take the `100%` of the **parent element**, and when does it take the `100%` of the **page**?

Comment: I think that when page is screen element or positioning is absolute

Answer (score 2):

`<img>` tags have an implicit width of either the image's natural width or the `width` attribute of the tag that must be overriden with css. Try this to make the image 100% of the width of its parent `<div>`:

```
div img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding of what cascading actually is. I'd recommend reading the [part of the spec that deals with the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade).

Comment: this method is best because it will retain the image's proportion.

Answer (score 0):

Your style selector only matches elements with the class `box`.  The `div` has that class, but the `img` doesn't.  Thus, the `div` has the style applied and the `img` doesn't.  Try:

```
.box
{
  padding:0px;
  margin-left:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.box, .box img
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}

<div class="box">
  <img src="larrow.gif"/>
</div>
```